# svg vs canvas for dashboard widgets

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

Here I can see this dashboard uses svg http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/dashboards/car-dashboard.html

Why not canvas?

Also could the needle be interactive (support event in svg)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one of the main advantages in SVG is the access to the DOM and its persistence. This inherits the benefits of the HTML counterparts, one of them being the ability to listen for Mouse events in a traditional way. More info [here](http://www.distractable.net/coding/svg-vs-canvas/), [here](http://smus.com/canvas-vs-svg-performance) and [here](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/svg-or-canvas-choosing-between-the-two/)

Comment: Great thanks then why do people most talk about Canvas instead of SVG ?